# Applying Menger's theorem to graph with 2k-1 non-disjoint paths

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph, $s,t$ be distinct non-adjacent vertices of $G$, and let $k\ge 1$.

If there exist $(2k-1)$ paths with ends $s$ and $t$. other vertices except for $s$ and $t$ belong to at most $2$ paths.

Show that there exists $k$ pairwise disjoint paths with ends $s$ and $t$.

My attempt is trying to prove that there is no seperation with order $<k$.

Answer (score 1):

> Theorem: (Menger) If $s,t$ are vertices of a graph $G$ and $st \not\in E(G)$, then the minimum size of an $s,t$-cut equals the maximum number of pairwise internally disjoint $s,t$-paths.

**Hint**: You are on the right track. Why is it that any set of $k-1$ vertices cannot possibly disconnect $s$ and $t$? What is the most number of $s,t$ paths that a set of $k-1$ vertices can get rid of? On the flip side, what contradiction can you reach if a $k-1$ $s,t$-cut exists?

Obtaining a lower bound on the size of a $s,t$-cut allows you to conclude the desired result using Menger's Theorem.

Comment: If there exists a seperation with order $k-1$ and the vertices except s and t belong to at most 2 paths, then every path from s to t must go through the cut. Then, number of path is at most 2(k-1)=2k-2. which contradicts that there are 2k-1 paths. then, there is no existence of a (k-1) cut. By Menger's theorem, there exists k disjoint paths. Is this the right approach?

Comment: @buzhidaojiaoshenm Sounds about right to me. In other words, there must be a vertex in the cut-set that belongs to more than $2$ paths.